# Could I modify lightbox2 to play mp4 videos on a php website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, lightbox

Hi my question is pretty much the title Could I modify lightbox2 to play mp4 videos on a PHP website.

The only additional part I would need to really say is that I also need it to run within PHP so that i can modify the SRC for the videos any ideas ??

Comment: Simple answer. Yes you could modify it to play videos. Though I'm not sure how easy this would be.  Are the videos on your server or on a video site like youtube?
  
I am not sure what you mean when you say you need it to run in PHP. Lightbox is javascript and runs client side.

Comment: @2pha when i mean i need it to run in php i mean the html that is used would need to be within php and then returned to the screen

Comment: You would need to use ajax to request the new html to insert. I'm not exactly sure why you would need this though as you could probably use data attributes to store what you need and then read the values when the link is clicked to open the video

Comment: the reason i needed this was because i have a website that you choose options from drop downboxes and this uses a sql query to bring back content what i wanted to do was for each piece of content i want to be able to stream it so the src would need to change depending on the name of the file baught back @2pha

Comment: Why not do the sql query and store the needed data on the option on the initial page load. Then just use javascript to manipulate the data. See this example of one using the value and another using a data attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/5hTMA/1/

Comment: cause what i want to do is is just use a .row["hello"]. within the href and then this will work how i want it to its just trying to find a way of getting the lightbox to work in the php @2pha

Comment: Lightbox is javascript and runs client side, not PHP. Make your PHP output a data attribute or value in the option tag like I showed and then you can use it.